# Validation error, when creating Event Class Family

Tags: kaa

I'm curently working on setting up my first Event Class Family in Kaa 0.10.0.

And i keep getting the following error:

Schema validation error: Undefined name: "com.xxx.types.HvacType"

Although the referenced Type has been created in the Tenant CTL.

CTL:

```
{
```

"type": "record",
  "classType": "object",
  "namespace": "com.xxx.types",
  "name": "HvacType",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": "int"
    },
    {
      "name": "name",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}

ECF:

[
  {
    "type": "record",
    "namespace": "com.xxx.request",
    "name": "ChangeSelectedHvacTypeRequest",
    "classType": "event",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "selected",
        "type": [
          "com.xxx.types.HvacType"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "dependencies": [
      {
        "fqn": "com.xxx.types.HvacType",
        "version": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]

Comment: Any take on this? :)

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong type of field "selected" "type": [ "com.xxx.types.HvacType" ]

Type of this field mast be a "record".
Please use [official avro documentation](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/spec.html#schema_record). Also you can use [avro ui](https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Getting-started/#avro-ui) shema builder of kaa project.